# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate batch size

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to set the batch size for Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate object?

I ran into some OutOfMemory issues in my project but I was able to resolve it by calling NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in a loop of smaller chunks. But this required some extra effort like deciding the chunk size, breaking a big List into smaller sublists etc.

I was wondering if NamedParameterJdbcTemplate has any such direct way by I can specify the batch size for it. I do not see anything though in the API documentation. But they have something in JDBCTemplate. Now if I have to switch to JDBCTemplate I will have to redo my code :(

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but you can call [#getJdbcOperations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcOperations.html#getJdbcOperations--) method via implemented `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` interface. Its return type, `JdbcOperations`, is currently implemented only by classic `JdbcTemplate` and has [#batchUpdate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-int-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter-) method that you need. However, you can't use named parameters in this scenario.

See the [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-batch-multi) of typical usage from Spring docs.